# remote sql script from jenkins

Tags: oracle, jenkins, ssh

I am suppose to run an sql script which is in a remote box the manual steps are as below after connecting to the box with userid and password
    
Then sudo su – fa3dev
    
account Password:*******
    
sqlplus / as sysdba
    
connect XX_fusion_custom
    
password *****
    
@abc.sql
When I run this manually all works fine
When I run from jenkins as a  remote shell script as below

**ssh fa3dev@server 'source .bash_profile; sqlplus xx_fusion_custom/password'**

In console it gives Sql connected and disconnected

if I run **ssh fa3dev@server 'source .bash_profile; sqlplus xx_fusion_custom/password;sqlplus / as sysdba;connect XX_fusion_custom;select user from dual'**
it gives syntax error near unexpected token `from' in jenkins console , i guess I am not able to connect to the database , any help in this would really be appriciable, I cannot user SQL plugin as I cant install oracle cleint in the jenkins box

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

your problem is in the bash, the sql command `select user from dual` is being executed after sqlplus exits and the bash picks it up.

You can fix this in 2 ways:

1. `echo` into the sqlplus:

   `ssh fa3dev@server 'source .bash_profile; echo select user from dual | sqlplus xx_fusion_custom/password;sqlplus / as sysdba;connect XX_fusion_custom;'`
2. Pass a file with the command (this is nice if the SQL commands are many and fixed)

2.1 Remote file

```
ssh fa3dev@server 'source .bash_profile; sqlplus xx_fusion_custom/password;sqlplus / as sysdba;connect XX_fusion_custom < files_with_commands.sql'
```

2.2 Local file (note the position of the closing `'` changed from after thehfilename to before the filename):

```
ssh fa3dev@server 'source .bash_profile; sqlplus xx_fusion_custom/password;sqlplus / as sysdba;connect XX_fusion_custom < files_with_commands.sql'
```

Comment: it worked like charm the  closing ' did the trick thankx a ton

Comment: Hi @subrata-fouzdar if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I would have definitely accepted but I dont have the option to accept it , I guees the reason being the question marked by the mod as off topic not sure why exactly....